# Why i'm getting syntax error?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm getting syntax error when i type this code in Python.

```
    class Initialize:
         int var
    def__init__(self,var=10):
           initialize.var=var
    def display():
         print var
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: there is an error in your program:invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

what is 'int var' doing here we don't have type declaration in python.

if you want to declare a variable in python inside a class just simply write

```
var=0
```

moreover in class we intialize don't initialize variable we actually intialize the object of that class, how we do that. here's an example:

```
class Initialize:
        var=0
        def __init__(self,var=10):
               self.var=var
        def display():
             print self.var
```

Comment: actually this is the code given in ncert python textbook for class 12'th

Comment: can you mention the name of the book? if such books are taught our future developers, just imagine the quality of developers we will get

Comment: NCERT COMPUTER SCIENCE-CLASS 12  (PYTHON ) .Link to screenshot of the book-  https://drive.google.com/file/d/14hUpfS-i2hapK3_TEFpUTJ7kP-XKPC3O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I understand bro, I just want the name of the book. we can claim to the publishing institute for this. I never wanted this as proof. :)